# Convert Special Characters php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the string in my database field as `Helloâ?¢ Buddy` whose encoding is `UTF-8`. Now the same string is present in my php variable as `Hello™ Buddy`. On applying `utf8_encode("Hello™ Buddy")` it prints `Helloâ.¢ Buddy` not this `Helloâ?¢ Buddy`

How can i convert my php variable to `Helloâ?¢ Buddy` so that in `where` clause of `mysql` query I can check both one.

Comment: Looks like your database field contains a value that's been UTF8-encoded twice (or which didn't need to be UTF8-encoded). You may want to check the part of your app that saves it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken `utf8_encode()` is for ISO-8859-1 to utf 8

Comment: @frz3993 seems to be right. I believe you don't require the `utf8_encode` conversion at all. I think when the data is received by your database it will automatically convert to utf-8. Please try and confirm.